# How to refresh combobox after changing selection in another combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have to combobox in my window:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDeps"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="sName" SelectedValuePath="nDepartmentIdn"
        Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,52,215,0" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="cbUsers_SelectionChanged"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cbUsersDep"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="sUserName" SelectedValuePath="nUserIdn"
        Grid.Row="0" Margin="218,52,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

and I want when I select a value in the first combobox, the second be filled only by items of the selected item. I get these items using this method:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataModel.TB_USER> listUsersParDeps(int numDep)
{
    var userDeps = (from DataModel.TB_USER ud in SessionContext.DBContext.TB_USER
                    where ud.nDepartmentIdn==numDep
                    select ud);

    foreach (var userDep in userDeps)
    {
        userM.ListUserDep.Add(userDep);
    }

    return userM.ListUserDep;
}
```

and I put them in the datacontext:

```
cbUsersDep.DataContext = userVM.listUsersParDeps(int.Parse(cbDeps.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

Comment: Can you check what is the data structure of the object that you are putting into the cbUsersDep.DataContext. 
Ideally you should do this: from cbUsers_SelectionChanged of first combo raise userVM.RaisePropertyChanged("listUsersParDeps").
This is basically asking the UI to update itself and get value from property.

Comment: How can I check the data structure of the object?

Comment: You can check in this line itself. cbUsersDep.DataContext = userVM.listUsersParDeps(int.Parse(cbDeps.SelectedValue.ToString()));

Comment: Are you new to programming ?

Comment: No, but just I didn't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the data context of each combo box manually, you should set the data context of the outer component (usually the window, or some other *“larger”* component) to your view model. Then you expose two lists (ideally [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)) for your two combo boxes and bind the `ItemSource` properties of your combo boxes to those lists. And then, whenever the `SelectedItem` of your first combo box changes, you update the second list:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDepartment}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // this holds the data
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> departmentUsers = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();

    private List<string> departments;
    public List<string> Departments
    {
        get { return departments; }
        set
        {
            if (value != departments)
            {
                departments = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Departments");
            }
        }
    }

    private string selectedDepartment;
    public string SelectedDepartment
    {
        get { return selectedDepartment; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selectedDepartment)
            {
                selectedDepartment = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDepartment");

                // update users list
                Users = departmentUsers[selectedDepartment];
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> users;
    public List<string> Users
    {
        get { return users; }
        set
        {
            if (value != users)
            {
                users = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Users");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // sample data
        departmentUsers = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        departmentUsers.Add("Department 1", new List<string>() { "1.1", "1.2", "1.3" });
        departmentUsers.Add("Department 2", new List<string>() { "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", "2.5" });
        departmentUsers.Add("Department 3", new List<string>() { "3.1", "3.2" });
        departmentUsers.Add("Department 4", new List<string>() { "4.1", "4.2", "4.3" });

        // initial state
        Departments = new List<string>(departmentUsers.Keys);
        SelectedDepartment = Departments[0];
    }

    // simple INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem now is that when I change the department combo value, the list in users combo doesn't change. It still has  the first values.

Comment: It doesn't handle the event for Users list

Comment: My code works like that; if you change the department, you get to choose different users from the second combo box. If you also want to listen to changes there, just bind a new property to the `SelectedItem` property of the second combo box.

Comment: I think I have to create an other method for ListChanged, no?

Comment: No, you add `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"`, and then a property `SelectedUser` in your view model where you do stuff in the property’s setter; like I did where the “update users list” comment is.

Comment: so I have to do like that         private ObservableCollection<String> selectedUser;
        public ObservableCollection<String> SelectedUser
        {
            get { return selectedUser; }
            set
            {
                if (value != selectedUser)
                {
                    selectedUser = value;
                    OnNotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");

                }
            }
        }

Comment: sorry I'm new in this language

Comment: I think you didn't understand me I'm talking about the list of users of the selected department. not selected user